# How to delete the default first row in the DataGridView in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I would like to delete the first row of the `DataGridView` before adding any rows through the program.

Instead of deleting through the program, I would rather remove the first row from the `DataGridView` properties.

Any Idea how to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by "default first row". I think you mean the empty row that appears on the editable grid - meaning you want to only add rows programatically, not allowing users to enter rows themselves. If my answer or Fuex's don't help please try to edit your question to make it clearer what you mean.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You appear to be referring to the default new row on an editable `DataGridView` which allows users to add a new row to the grid using the UI.

To stop this row from appearing you simply set the `DataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows` property to false, either programatically or in the designer.